# Variation of Intrinsic losses w.r.t spring constant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, spring

How intrinsic friction losses (or energy losses) of a real spring varies w.r.t its spring constant? I am not expecting a direct relationship between the two, but at least whether more stiffer springs results in more internal damping losses or not?

Comment: I'd expect this to depend strongly on the deformation mechanism. Are you interested in a particular class of materials, such as metals, polymers, biological materials...?

Comment: I am asking about metals, more specifically steel alloys that are used to make springs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rigid material or object (the limit of stiffness → infinity) can have no hysteretic losses because deformation work can't be performed on it anyway. However, all real materials with finite stiffness exhibit internal friction/damping. It's therefore reasonable to assume that—all else being equal—hysteretic losses decrease with increasing stiffness.